# How long do it take to fully format USB drive 2TB 2.0?

Tags: windows, usb, file-transfer, formatting, file-corruption

Since I can't find any answer from the internet, I hope someone will help me here.

I have just bought a 3.5$ USB drive 2TB 2.0. When I transfer my video file to the USB, the 3 first video is working normally, but at my 4 video file, the video is corrupted and can't be open.

After that all video file copy to the USB is all corrupted, so I search internet and use chkdsk in cmd, there is a loop that make the cmd keep founding error and don't stop. Therefore I try to quick format the USB

Then I try to transfer my video again, some first video still work but the later is still corrupted and this time, chkdsk and error checking don't find any error but the videos is still corrupted. I have tried to use "check flash" to see if the USB fake the size but it still run to 672 GB without warning anything so I decide to stop that "check flash"

Because all of my videos is about 3 - 6 GB, so I try to fully format the USB and convert it to NTFS. However, it already take 32 hours now and the progress bar is just almost half, is this normal or this USB is some kind of fake? Should I continue to wait for the format or should I cancel and find other method?

Comment: Three dollars & fifty cents for a 2TB drive? Really, unless you meant three hundred and fifty dollars, you likely bought a fake.

Comment: here is the link to that product if anyone wonder: 
https://shopee.vn/product/135237146/13849701047?d_id=c06dc&utm_content=23eiWYfr5v5u8k138G4mARhDiZps

I bought it at Viet Nam, Thanks for all of your answer to my issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is "a 3.5$ USB drive 2TB 2.0".
There's nothing like that. It's a scam. Basically, it's a 1/2/4GB drive, configured to show that it has more storage. The first copy might work, but the second will have less chance to succeed.

Nobody wil manufacturer 2TB 2.0 USB sticks nowdays since it'll take forever to fill, it'll heat too-much and it'll cost way more than $3.5.

Just thank your gods for figuring it now, and not in six-months, when you'll want to view the important material you moved there.

You can see these videos for similiar products/scams:
[Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOhLlvNlI20) [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kix3JKn08OU) [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-D6tYBX8vE)

If you want 2TB HDD, then buy an internal HDD from a respected company and an enclosure. You can do the same with SSD to increase speed and lower the weight ( there are enclosures for 3.5/2.5-SATA and M.2 connectors )

Comment: thanks for your reply, I just feel weird when 'check flash' still run without any error.

Comment: Don't think about it too much. I'm not familiar with "check flash" but it depends on what it does; It might see that the entire 4GB are actually clean and working, but isn't aware that it's pretending to be 2TB... It might be many other reasons.